# website forcing to disable adblocker how to get rid of this

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browsing, advertisements

following is the link which I am trying to open in my Windows 8.1 laptop.
http://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com/business/business-news/why-constitutional-amendment-for-gst/articleshow/53516496.cms?utm_source=facebook.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=GSTConst030816

Now whenever I open above link on Chrome I get following screen,
[image]
[image]

How do I get rid of this problem and be able to read the articles as usual.
I don't have any adblocker installed on my laptop.
I have following extensions however 
 1) Chrome RDP 4.5.1.23
 2) Chrome Remote Desktop 41.0.2272.41
 3) Firebug Lite for Google Chrome™ 1.4.0.11967
 4) Flashcontrol 9.2.415
 5) MySmartPrice 2.0 2.1

Comment: Use another browser. And then email them to let them know there may be a bug

Comment: Loads fine with Firefox 48.0/uBlock Origin 1.8.0

Answer (score 1):

**The flashcontrol plugin may be causing this.**

This plugin prevents flash content from loading until you allow it, and it is likely blocking flash ads on the site, in a manner similar to an ad blocker.

Try disabling the plugin for this site.

*Update: I installed that plugin on Chrome to test it myself, and I'm not seeing this behavior.  But the plugin also doesn't seem to be working properly for me (i.e. it is not blocking Flash content).  So I still suspect this is the culprit for you.*